# SQL Server - Select value of column with most frequent record for user

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 1 table called `day_shift`, with columns: `employee_id`, `shop_id` and `date`.

I need to create SELECT query to my DB table to get `shop_id` for each `employee_id` ordered by the highest amount of `date`-records. **Main idea:** **Employee able to work in any shop, programm add day-shift by `shop_id` ordered to date, but Employee will be assigned to the department in which it appears more often.**

Actual query that give just first record in table by `employee_id`:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 shop_id FROM day_shift WHERE employee_id = ?1 ORDER BY date desc
```

How to get `shop_id` with most frequent **equal** record `date` for user?

[EDIT 1]: Table also contain column `id` but I dont use it in query.

Comment: Hang on a second, `TOP` is either SQL Server or Access syntax, not MySQL.  Which database are you actually using here?

Comment: You have to use group by clause for date column

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, oh my God! Sorry! MS SQL Server, you'r right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> to get shop_id for each employee_id ordered by the highest amount of date-records.

I think you are using SQL Server.  In any case, building on your query syntax, you would use:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES employee_id, shop_id, date, COUNT(*)
FROM day_shift
GROUP BY employee_id, shop_id, date
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC);
```

If you want this just for one employee:

```
SELECT TOP (1) employee_id, shop_id, date, COUNT(*)
FROM day_shift
WHERE employee_id = ?
GROUP BY employee_id, shop_id, date
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you! It is working correct. My result looks like 
`SELECT TOP 1 shop_id 
FROM day_shift
WHERE employee_id = ?1 AND shop_id is not null 
GROUP BY employee_id, shop_id, date 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC`